# Debian Wheezy can not use LDOCE5

Tags: debian

I have installed LDOCE5 (Longman Dictionary of Contemporary English Edition 5) on  Debian Wheezy 7.6 adm64, and I have installed `libc6` by the following method:

```
dpkg --add-architecture i386 # enable multi-arch
apt-get update
apt-get install libc6:i386 # install base 32bit libraries
```

Then I ran the command `./ldoce5` which returned the following error:

```
./ldoce5-bin: error while loading shared libraries: libgtk-x11-2.0.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

So, I tried the following:

```
$ locate libgtk-x11-2.0.so.0
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgtk-x11-2.0.so.0
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgtk-x11-2.0.so.0.2400.10
```

Then I constructed a link by

```
$ sudo ln -s /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgtk-x11-2.0.so.0  .
```

followed by:

```
$ ./ldoce5
./ldoce5-bin: error while loading shared libraries: libgtk-x11-2.0.so.0: wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS64
```

I guessed that it maybe  do the work if I have successed in installing `ia32-libs-gtk-i386:i386` and `ia32-libs-i386:i386`, for I have tried this method successfully on Linuxmint Qiana. But when I tried to install the two packages, the result is of great trouble, for there are many dependence problems:

```
$ sudo apt-get install ia32-libs-i386:i386 ia32-libs-gtk-i386:i386
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 ia32-libs-gtk-i386:i386 : Depends: gtk2-engines-pixbuf:i386 (>= 2.20.1-2) but it is not going to be installed
                       Depends: gtk2-engines:i386 (>= 1:2.20.1-1) but it is not going to be installed
                       Depends: libcanberra-gtk-module:i386 (>= 0.24-1) but it is not going to be installed
                       Depends: libcanberra-gtk0:i386 (>= 0.24-1) but it is not going to be installed
                       Depends: libgail-common:i386 (>= 2.20.1-2) but it is not going to be installed
                       Depends: libgail18:i386 (>= 2.20.1-2) but it is not going to be installed
                       Depends: libgtk2.0-0:i386 (>= 2.20.1-2) but it is not going to be installed
                       Recommends: libbonobo2-0:i386 (>= 2.24.3-1) but it is not going to be installed
                       Recommends: libglade2-0:i386 (>= 1:2.6.4-1) but it is not going to be installed
                       Recommends: libgnomecanvas2-0:i386 (>= 2.30.1-1) but it is not going to be installed
                       Recommends: libidl0:i386 (>= 0.8.14-0.1) but it is not going to be installed
                       Recommends: liborbit2:i386 (>= 1:2.14.18-0.1) but it is not going to be installed
 ia32-libs-i386:i386 : Depends: libcups2:i386 (>= 1.4.4-7+squeeze1) but it is not going to be installed
                   Depends: libcurl3:i386 (>= 7.21.0-2) but it is not going to be installed
                   Depends: libgnutls26:i386 (>= 2.8.6-1) but it is not going to be installed
                   Depends: libpulse0:i386 (>= 0.9.21-3+squeeze1) but it is not going to be installed
                   Depends: libsdl1.2debian:i386 (>= 1.2.15) but it is not going to be installed
 libsmbclient : Depends: libtdb1 (>= 1.2.7+git20101214) but it is not going to be installed
E: Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages.
```

How could I have LDOCE5 work right on Wheezy?

Answer (score 0):

[HOWTO: Install LDOCE5 on Ubuntu 64-bit](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1387641)

Google before ask, Ubuntu and Debian are extremely similar, and I can be really sure this would work.

Comment: Actually, I have tried to install LDOCE5 by the same method I posted above on my another OS, LinuxMint 17, and it did work well. I do not know why this method dose not work on Debian Wheezy?

Comment: Linux Mint is based on Ubuntu, Ubuntu is based on Debian, compatibility goes down the chain FROM Debian, just like your mum probably spend more time with you than her mother. Also, Linux Mint and Ubuntu is commercially supported, and Debian isn't.